# How to check if an array contains empty elements?

Tags: php

Let's make some examples:

```
array("Paul", "", "Daniel") // false
array("Paul", "Daniel") // true
array("","") // false
```

What's a neat way to work around this function?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try using [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
return !in_array("", array("Paul", "", "Daniel")); //returns false
```

Comment: @stereofrog Take a look at the PHP documentation, unless you pass `true` as a third parameter, `in_array` will do a loose comparison, so it'll give the same results with `array("Paul", 0, "Daniel")`, `array("Paul", "", "Daniel")` or `array("Paul", false, "Daniel")`. So if the op only wants to match empty string, he could just pass `true` as the third parameter.

Comment: @stereofrog 0 is actually a number and so it's not an empty string.

Comment: @stereofrog @David If you don't want to return `false` if a 0 is in the array, and _only_ on an empty string, just pass `true` as the third parameter.

Answer (score 34):

The answer depends on how you define "empty"

```
$contains_empty = count($array) != count(array_filter($array));
```

this checks for empty elements in the [boolean sense](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). To check for empty strings or [equivalents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

```
$contains_empty = count($array) != count(array_filter($array, "strlen"));
```

To check for empty strings only (note the third parameter):

```
$contains_empty = in_array("", $array, true);
```

Comment: Super clever way to save a couple lines of code checking for the existence of values in an array!

Answer (score 8):

So [`array_filter()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will remove empty the elements from the array and then return this array.

Comparing the returned array to the original array would not be the same.
Meaning the array contains one or more empty elements.

```
$array = array("Paul", "", "Daniel");
if($array != array_filter($array)) {
    echo "Array contains empty values.";
}
```

Comment: Explain a bit will ya ?

Comment: This is beautiful and straight forward! +1

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed So `array_filter` will remove entities that are "false" (=empty) and return the array back without empty elements at it. Meaning if the data is not equal to the original array, the array contains empty values.

Answer (score 5):

```
function has_empty(array $array)
{
    return count($array) != count(array_diff($array, array('', null, array())));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function testEmpty($array) {
  foreach ($array as $element) {
    if ($element === '')
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Please check out the comments down below for more information.

Comment: Depending on how you define "empty" elements, you might want to look at if (empty($element)) instead of if ($element == ""). empty() treats "", false, 0, null (and probably some more) as empty elements.

Comment: @sbrattla I only gave an answer to that precise question, but you're write, your answer is more global.

Comment: @Oltatus: Not my intention to correct your suggestion, it was more of an additional solution :-) The empty() function isn't always a good choice, especially if the array would be an array holding true/false values. In that case, all 'false' values would be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do enjoy me some fancy anonymous functions here is my take on it. Not sure about performance, but here it is:

```
$filter = array_filter(
        ["Paul", "", "Daniel"],
        static function ($value) {
            return empty($value); // can substitute for $value === '' or another check
        }
    );

return (bool) count($filter);
```

Logically explained. If anonymous returns true, it means that it found an empty value. Which means the filter array will contain only empty values at the end (if it has any).

That's why the return checks if the filter array has values using `count` function.

The `(bool)` type cast is equivalent to `return count($filter) === 0`.

May you all find the happiness you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to the question, but many visitors come here by searching for a solution to this slightly different case:

## Check, if an array **ONLY contains empty strings**

This would be a simple solution with `implode()`, that will fit to some needs

```
function testIfEmpty($array) {
    $flat = implode('', $array);
    return !empty($flat):
}
```