# How to check if an array have [0] index but no value?

Tags: php

I am in a very specific situation where I have an indexed array `$name_array`, which have **0** index but don't have values, as follow;

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

I want to consider this array as empty, I've checked it in `isset($name_array)` and `!empty($name_array)` but this array is passing both condition. I don't know What condition should I apply to detect if this array has these kind of values then it is empty?

for eg;

```
if(/*some condition*/($name_array)) 
{
    echo 'I am not empty';
}
else
{
    echo 'I am empty';
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an array contains empty elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621683/how-to-check-if-an-array-contains-empty-elements)

Comment: @Apb No, its not duplicate of above question, Both questions are completely different.

Comment: There are many links related to your question on SO. Google it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040811/checking-if-all-the-array-items-are-empty-php

Comment: $name_array = array_filter($name_array);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
if (!array_filter($name_array)) {
    // empty or has "empty" values
}
```

By default `array_filter` filters out any "empty" values like empty string, `null` or `false`.

Comment: Yeah I changed It as 
`if (array_filter($name_array)) {
echo 'I am not empty';
}
else
{
echo 'I am empty';
}`

working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

[`!empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is enough to check your first index of array is valid or not:-

```
if(!empty($array[0])){
 // $array[0] has value
}
```

In case of Multidimensional array where you don't know first index key,

```
if(!empty($array[key($array)])){
  echo $array[key($array)];
}
```

**empty - Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.**

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Comment: @devpro: In question, OP has defined index [0] of array. So I have suggested this way :)

Comment: yes, thats way i said, solution is fine... not ideal :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function to check that 
you can create your own instead :) here an example

```
function is_array_empty($name_array) {
    foreach($name_array as $elm) {
        if(!empty($elm)) return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you only trying to check if the first element is empty? if so:

```
if ( ! current($name_array)) {
    // first element in $name_array is niether false, null, 0 or an empty string
}
```

if you need to check a more specific case, just change the exclamation mark into whatever it is you need checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
function is_array_empty($name_array) {
    $arrSize=sizeof($name_array);
    $emptElements=0;
    foreach($name_array as $elm) {
        if(empty($elm)){
           $emptElements++;
        }
    }
    if($emptElements==$arrSize){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: too long... check @ksimka's answer.