# Better method to write a long logical condition in PHP

Tags: php

How could I improve the following statement:

```
if(!empty($var1) && !empty($var2) && !empty($var3) && !empty($var4) && !empty($var5) && !empty($var6) && !empty($var7)....)
```

Is there a PHP function that allows chaining of logical conditions?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: you could keep your variables in an array and iterate over it to determine if any of the items is empty...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this way also,

```
$not_empty = false;
$required_fields = [$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7];
foreach ($required_fields as $f) {
    if (!empty($f)) {
       $not_empty = true;
    }else{
       $not_empty = false;
       break;
    }
}

if($not_empty){
  //good to go
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could do something like that :

```
$n = 7;
$empty = false;
foreach(range(1, $n) as $v)
{
    if(empty(${'var' . $v})){
        $empty = true;
    }
}

if(!$empty){
    echo 'no empty variables';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2):

The answers submitted so far could be written up into a little utility function. Here's an *untested* function that takes a variable amount of arguments.

```
function all_empty() {
  // Grab the number of arguments passed to the function.
  $numberOfArguments = func_num_args();
  $arguments = func_get_args();
  $output = true;

  // Return if nothing was passed.
  if($numberOfArguments == 0) {
    return;
  }

  // Check each passed argument, break on failure.
  foreach($arguments as $argument) {
    if(!empty($argument)) {
      $output = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Using similar methods, we can write a function called `none_empty`:

```
function none_empty() {
  // Grab the number of arguments passed to the function.
  $numberOfArguments = func_num_args();
  $arguments = func_get_args();
  $output = true;

  // Return if nothing was passed.
  if($numberOfArguments == 0) {
    return;
  }

  // Check each passed argument, break on failure.
  foreach($arguments as $argument) {
    if(empty($argument)) { // This is the only difference.
      $output = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  return $output;
}
```

**Usage examples:**

```
if(all_empty($var1, $var2, $var3)) { /* They're all empty */ }
if(!all_empty($var1, $var2, $var3)) { /* Some of them aren't empty */ }
if(none_empty($var1, $var2, $var3)) { /* They all have a value */ }
if(!none_empty($var1, $var2, $var3)) { /* Some of them are empty */ }
```

And since we wrote the functions to be able to take a variable amount of arguments, this is possible as well:

```
if(all_empty($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, ...)) { }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

To be more readable, you could make "groups" (could be one or multiple) of conditions and divide it to make multiple lines:

```
if(!empty($var1) &&
   !empty($var2) &&
   !empty($var3) &&
   !empty($var4) &&
   !empty($var5) &&
   !empty($var6) &&
   !empty($var7) ...) {
```

What you could also do with issets and unsets, you could shorten:

```
if(!isset($var1) &&
   !isset($var2) &&
   !isset($var3) &&
   !isset($var4) &&
   !isset($var5) &&
   !isset($var6) &&
   !isset($var7) ...) {
```

to

```
if(isset($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6, $var7)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create an array of variables to check and loop to see if any of them are empty.

```
$check = array(
    'var1',
    'var2',
    'var3',
    'var4',
    'var5',
    'var6',
    'var7',
);


$empty = false;
foreach($check as $value){
    if(empty(${$value})){
        $empty = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($empty){
    // there is an empty value
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329035/1824143

```
function has_empty(array $array)
{
    return count($array) != count(array_diff($array, array('', null, array())));
}

$vars = [$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7];
if(!has_empty($vars))
{
  ...
}
```